# How to redraw a dynamically sized UIView within a collection cell

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`, and inside each `UICollectionViewCell` is a `UIView` that I am sizing dynamically based on the content...

From the data source I am setting a model on the cell:

```
extension CategoryViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // Show quiz thumbnail and name
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: QuizViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! QuizViewCell

        cell.quiz = self.quizzes[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

`cell.quiz` is a computed property. When it is set, I calculate the width of a "progress bar" based on the difficulty. For simplicity I am just setting it to 100 here.

```
class QuizViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var difficultyBar: UIView!

    var quiz: Quiz? {
        didSet {
            configure(quiz)
        }
    }

    private func configure(_ quiz: Quiz?) {
        if let quiz = quiz {
            difficultyBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 6)

            // Attempt to redraw bar, but doesn't work
            setNeedsLayout()
            layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

I know that if it weren't for the collection, I could just call `view.layoutIfNeeded()` on the controller to force it to redraw the bar now that its width has been set. But I can't figure out where or how to force it to redraw a view that is within a cell within a collection view.

Comment: did you try with reloadItems(at:[IndexPaths]) method?

Comment: @Van I only tried calling `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` on various views in different places. I just tried `reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` after setting `cell.quiz` but that didn't seem to work either. Should I put that somewhere else?

Comment: even in cell you can do cell.layoutIfNeeded() in your cellForRowAt or just relaod your cells again, Just one question what is happening currently, it's not drawing?

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh thanks, I didn't know I could call that directly on the cell. However I tried that (see edit above) and that still doesn't work. The bar remains at width 0. I have top, leading, and bottom constraints and a "placeholder" width in the storyboard, but no width or trailing constraint.

Comment: you either have to give trailing or width constraint and if you are setting constraints then changes frame will not work you need to create IBOulet for difficultyBar width and then have to. change it

Comment: @Van the problem is not cell height but the width of difficultyBar, and he is using contrainst , changing frames will not work

Comment: @andrewtweber call the method after setting the difficultyBar.frame may be you will need to create protocol and add deifinition in view controller for same

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh yes got that :)

Comment: @Van thanks for the suggestion. I was already working on Iraniya's constraint outlet idea which worked :)

Comment: @andrewtweber Great..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments changing frames will not work as you are using constraints

So create constraints for difficultyBar width

```
@IBOutlet weak var difficultyBarWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! //set this to the width of difficultyBar
```

then in QuizViewCell update the width contrainsts constant

```
private func configure(_ quiz: Quiz?) {
    if let quiz = quiz {
        if difficultyBarWidthConstraint != nil {
            difficultyBarWidthConstraint.constant  = 100// width you want to set
        }

    }
}
```

let me know if this works :-)

Comment: Thank you, I just finished doing the exact thing from your comment :)